# How do I make my desktop computer screen brighter

Tags: brightness

Is there a way to make my computer screen brighter? It is a desktop, not a laptop, and it doesn't have the same power options a laptop has. If there is no way to do it, is there a program I can download that will give me the option to make the screen brighter?

Answer (score 3):

The maximum brightness of a computer monitor is determined by the monitor itself. It's a physical property determined by the components (mostly [backlight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backlight)). Every monitor, regardless of technology, should have a brightness setting which you can manually adjust. Once that's set to 100%, you can't go brighter than that.

This means that no software will be able to help you there.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to your graphics card manufacturer, you can find the appropriate software coming with the device driver.
In my case i am using an integrated Intel HD graphics card and this is a screen capture where you can adjust many options including Brightness.

[image]